# Split Large Dataframe into multiple dataframes based on Column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a very large Dataframe with more than 3000 columns. Column names starts with `items_0_****  |  items_0_****  |  items_1_****    | items_1_****` and so on up to `items_99_***` .
I want to Split my Large DataFrame in such a way that `items_0_***` in one Dataframe, `items_1_****` in one Dataframe and so up to `items_99_****` in one DataFrame.

So Finally I need to get 100 Data Frames.

Column names starting with `items_0_` must be in one Dataframe.
Column names starting with `items_1_` must be in another Dataframe.
.

.

.

Column names starting with `items_99_` must be in another Dataframe.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How do you want to retrieve your dataframes, from a dict?

Comment: Updated my Question, Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you want to retrieve your dataframes, from a dict?

If so:

```
my_dataframes = dict()

for i in range(100):
    my_dataframes[i] = df[[j for j in df.columns if j.startswith(f'items_{i}_')]]
```

Then, if you type `my_dataframes[0]`, you'll get a dataframe with the columns `items_0_****`

Comment: Is there any way to store each of them in different csv files?

Comment: You could put them all in a list, I guess? What do you want to do with them, once you have all your difference dataframes?

Comment: After I get all the different DataFrames , I need to merge them into one single DataFrame again, For Example : Columns `items_0_a` , `items_1_a`, `items_2_a` values should be in one single column.